# LowDB get value

Tags: javascript, json, database

I Want to get a value from LowDB Database to make a TODO app. Is there way to get it?

JSON:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "todo": "eat dinner"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "todo": "wash cloths"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the "todo" of the item with id=1  (in this example it is "wash cloths")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way to get `todo` value where the `id` value is 1,

```
console.log(db.get('content').find({"id": 1}).value().todo)
```